# Is it possible to enable legacy build system for buddy build?

Tags: buddy-build

We're trying to build a project on Buddy Build using Xcode 10. The project requires building with "legacy build system," but we can't seem to find how to enable this in the build settings in Buddy Build. Any one know how to do this so we can continue to use CI with Buddy Build?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to explicitly select the legacy build system.

We're running our project on xcode 9.4.1 until react native support for the new build system ships (tracking progress [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19573)).

If you're working on a react native project there's also a [workaround](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20774) available if you want to keep your BuddyBuild configured on the latest XCode release.